# GoZ- Blender to ZBrush - GoB

Tags: export, add-on, import, installation, zbrush

I would like to install a GoZ live link between ZBrush 2022 and Blender 3.0.

I have installed the GoB Add-on(v3_5_66)in Blender:Edit>Preferences>Add-ons.

In ZBrush I have updated >Preferences>GoZ> Path to Blender
with the relative path but I'm still getting errors.

I have followed the instructions in the installation folder but I keep getting errors on both ends.

[image]
[image]

It looks like I'm missing something and looking on the web the installation should be pretty straight-forward so any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks a lot to any one that could help.